# Regex to display the initial letters of the sentences replacing the remaining letters with asterisks or dots

Tags: powershell, batch, notepad++, regex

I try to find a regex to replace text in this format

```
balle spaziali
bambole e botte
calda emozione
fuori di testa
giovani diavoli
ragazze vincenti
ore contate
```

in this way

```
b.... s.......
b...... e b.....
c.... e......
f.... d. t....
g...... d......
r...... v.......
o.. c......
```

Have you idea?
 I use notepad++ as text editor, I don't know if I need a batch or powershell script.
Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<![^a-z])(?<!^)[a-z]`
- Replace with: `.`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<![^a-z])     # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't a non-letter before
(?<!^)          # negative lookbehind, make sure we aren't at the beginning of line
[a-z]           # a letter
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: In the explanation, the first line should read “_make sure we don't have a **non**-letter before_”

Comment: I've never imagined one can use two consecutive lookbehinds ... Nice one !

Answer (score 5):

You just need a regular expression to identify the characters that you want to convert. That is simple, either of the following will work: `\B\S`, or `\B\w`.

Now you need a tool to convert all matched characters to a `.`

I don't use notepad++, so I can't speak to how you would to it there. But this is simple using my [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) regular expression find/replace command line utility.

Let's assume you want to do the conversion to the file "file.txt":

```
jrepl "\B\S" "." /f file.txt /o -
```

or

```
jrepl "\B\w" "." /f file.txt /o -
```

If you put the command within a batch script, then you need to use `call jrepl` because JREPL is itself a batch script. Without CALL you will not return back to your script.

You can also transform piped text. Here is a simple example:

```
C:\test>echo hello world|jrepl "\B\S" "."
h.... w....
```

Comment: Strangely, in Notepad++ (7.6.4), this only replaces every other letter. Most likely because it reapplies the regex after each replacement.

Comment: @DidierL - Yes, very odd. I installed Notepad++ v7.8.9 just so I could test. But it looks like a serious bug to me, having nothing to do with replacement. Either regex only finds every other letter in Notepad++, even when doing find all (with no replacement).

Comment: @DidierL - Even weirder, `\S\B` works properly in notepad++ - it matches all but the last letter of each word. I can't imagine how that can work, yet `\B\S` does not.

Comment: I think the "replace all" feature works a bit like if you were clicking "replace" in a loop until reaching the end of the document. After "replace" the cursor is placed after the match/replacement. With `\B\S`, the next character would not match anymore, whereas it still matches `\S\B`. However, this is not entirely correct: clicking "replace" does not actually replace anything with this regex (at least in my version, so that's clearly a bug), and even a simple "find" also skips every other letter.

Comment: @DidierL - Nope, the lookbehind always looks at the source string, not the string after the most recent replacement (within the current find/replace "session"). I'm glad, else the look behind would be crippled for use with find/replace. Interestingly this is true even when performing the replace one character at a time as long as you don't close the dialog box. For example, finding `(?<!\d)[a-z]` and replacing with `0` will transform `1hello cruel9world` into `1h0000 000009w0000`. If it operated as you thought the result would be `1h0l0o 0r0e09w0r0d`

Answer (score 3):

Powershell Version Based on @dbenham RegEx

```
(Get-Content "Filepath") -replace '\B\w','.' | Set-Content "Filepath"
```